# Onclick on only one href addClass

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I have a one page HTML and those links on the header, I need every time I click one link `<a>` then only that `<a>` change class to (.links).

I have tried many methods but with this method I use now in my Jquery that every time I click on any `<a>` they all add class to (.links), and that is not what I'm looking for.

Should I use and class/ID for every `<a>` and target them all using Javascript/Jquery or there are any other easy method for that ?

```
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#HOME">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#SERVICES">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TEAM">TEAM</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PORTFOLIO">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PRICING">PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#BLOG">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#CONTACT">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
$('li').click(function(){
$('a').addClass('links');
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Target just the anchor inside the clicked LI

```
$('li').click(function(){
    $(this).find('a').addClass('links');
});
```

If you want to remove the class on the other anchors as well

```
$('li').click(function(){
    var this_one = $(this).find('a').addClass('links');
    $('li a').not(this_one).removeClass('links');
});
```

Comment: The first script for adding the class works, but the second one for removing the class on the other anchors doesn't work, can you please use If and else.

Answer (score 1):

Use `this` selector in jQuery.

```
<script>
   $('nav ul li').click(function(){
   $('nav ul li a').removeClass('links');
   $(this).find('a').addClass('links');
   });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`children()`](https://api.jquery.com/children/) api in jquery.It finds your DOM children as well.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#HOME">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#SERVICES">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TEAM">TEAM</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PORTFOLIO">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PRICING">PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#BLOG">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#CONTACT">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<script>
$('li').click(function(){
    $('a').removeClass('links');
    $(this).children().addClass('links');
});

</script>
```

Comment: Great, how about removing them if click on another anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Please find the attached code. It should possibly answer your issue.

```js
$('li').click(function(){
  $('li').not(this).each(function(index, li) {
    var anchor = $(li).find('a:first'); 
    anchor.removeClass('link');
   });
   $(this).find('a:first').addClass('link');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="#HOME">HOME</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#ABOUT">ABOUT US</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#SERVICES">SERVICES</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#TEAM">TEAM</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PORTFOLIO">PORTFOLIO</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#PRICING">PRICING</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#BLOG">BLOG</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#CONTACT">CONTACT</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$("a").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("links");
    $("a").not($(this)).removeClass("links");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
$('li').on('click', function() {
  $('.links').removeClass('.links');
  $(this).find('a').addClass('links');
})
```